# AmazonS3 dependency imports cannot be resolved

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, intellij-idea

I am writing the up the config file in my SpringBoot app, but it won't let me import from the dependency.

The dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.649</version>
</dependency>
```

My config file

```
package com.jringo.theDeniedList.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AmazonConfig {

    public AmazonS3 s3() {
        AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            "***", // accessKey
            "***"  // secretKey
        );
        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I ran File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart and that cleaned up the issue

Comment: You are welcome to answer your own question, but please add it as an Answer rather than as a Comment.